# UIKit button isExclusiveTouch equivalent in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In case you need to make only one button clickable at a time instead of letting user click on two buttons at the same time you can set `isExclusiveTouch` in `UIButton` to be `false`
the same issue happens in `SwiftUI` Button, but i couldn't find an equivalent to `isExclusiveTouch`, any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: The issue doesn't need an example since it's really basic

Comment: No, there is no one, and seems, due to reactive nature of SwiftUI, there will not be as it conflicts with a concept.

Comment: you can set `.disabled()` programmatically on all other buttons.

Comment: i wanted a solution to be applied on all buttons in the app to prevent such behavior